# spark-warehouse error in R

Tags: r, sparkr

I have installed spark `spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7` on my Windows 10 PC and I want to use SparkR package in R.
But when I run the following example code:

```
library(SparkR)

# Initialize SparkSession
sparkR.session(appName = "SparkR-DataFrame-example")

# Create a simple local data.frame
localDF <- data.frame(name=c("John", "Smith", "Sarah"), age=c(19, 23, 18))

# Convert local data frame to a SparkDataFrame
df <- createDataFrame(localDF)
```

it throws an exception:

```
Error in invokeJava(isStatic = TRUE, className, methodName, ...) :
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: file:C:/Users/Louagyd/Desktop/EDU%20%202016-2017/Data%20Analysis/spark-warehouse
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.initialize(Path.java:205)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.<init>(Path.java:171)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.makeQualifiedPath(SessionCatalog.scala:114)     
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.createDatabase(SessionCatalog.scala:145)    
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.<init>(SessionCatalog.scala:89)     
at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SessionState.catalog$lzycompute(SessionState.scala:95)     
at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SessionState.catalog(SessionState.scala:95)    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SessionState$$anon$1.<init>(SessionState.scala:112)    
at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SessionState.analyzer$lzycompute(SessionState.scala:112)   
at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SessionState.analyzer(Session
```

Any ideas how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error too but there was no help on Net. However, I solved this with below steps:

## Prep Work

1. Download winutils.exe from [here](https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils/blob/master/hadoop-2.6.0/bin/winutils.exe) and install it.
2. Create a folder called "C:\tmp\hive". This folder will be used as a *warehouse* directory.
3. In command prompt (**cmd**) run **winutils.exe chmod 777 \tmp\hive**. Ensure that winutils is in your classpath. If not, add it in the environment variables.
4. Ensure that SPARK is installed in your system. In my case, it was installed under "C:/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7" folder.

## Main

1. After opening RStudio create a new project in any directory (say, "C:/home/Project/SparkR")
2. In RStudio's script window, run the following commands in the same order:

   ```
   # Set Working Dir - The same folder under which R Project was created
   setwd("C:/home/Project/SparkR")

   # Load Env variable SPARK_HOME, if not already loaded.
   # If this variable is already set in Window's Env variable, this step is not required
   if (nchar(Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME")) < 1) {
     Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME = "C:/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7")
   }

   # Load SparkR library
   library(SparkR, lib.loc = c(file.path(Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME"), "R", "lib")))

   # Create a Config variable mapping Memory to be allocated and Warehouse directory to be referred during runtime.
   sparkConf = list(spark.driver.memory = "2g", spark.sql.warehouse.dir="C:/tmp")
   # Create SparkR Session variable
   sparkR.session(master = "local[*]", sparkConfig = sparkConf)

   # Load existing data from SparkR library
   DF <- as.DataFrame(faithful)
   # Inspect loaded data
   head(DF)
   ```

With the above steps, I could successfully load the data and view them.